# Crontab y Python con venv

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell, crontab

Estoy intentando programar con cron una tarea para un programa hecho en Python, el problema está en que aunque está programado, al ejecutarlo con el cron, me devuelve errores en el codigo que ejecutandolo manualmente no surgen, dejo la tarea que he programado en el crontab:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /home/victor/PycharmProjects/PybotProject/Post.py >> ~/cron.log 2>&1
```

por aqui dejo el log que me devuelve el cron al ejecutarse:

```
    June 27, 2019 at 1000AM(1).jpg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/victor/PycharmProjects/PybotProject/Post.py", line 51, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/victor/PycharmProjects/PybotProject/Post.py", line 32, in main
    os.chdir("./pics/")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './pics/'
15.jpg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/victor/PycharmProjects/PybotProject/Post.py", line 51, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/victor/PycharmProjects/PybotProject/Post.py", line 32, in main
    os.chdir("pics/")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pics/'
14.png
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/victor/PycharmProjects/PybotProject/Post.py", line 51, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/victor/PycharmProjects/PybotProject/Post.py", line 32, in main
    os.chdir("pics/")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pics/'
17.jpg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/victor/PycharmProjects/PybotProject/Post.py", line 51, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/victor/PycharmProjects/PybotProject/Post.py", line 32, in main
    os.chdir("pics/")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pics/'
```

Y aqui debajo dejo el codigo del programa de Python, en caso de que fuese necesario por cualquier cosa, es un bot que estoy haciendo para Twitter, pero necesito automatizarlo de momento para cada minuto:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import tweepy
import shutil, os
import testing

# Definimos una variable para que almacene el resultado del modulo que hemos creado anterior.
var = testing.result

# Damos las credenciales para el login en la API de Twitter
def main():
    twitter_auth_keys = {
        "consumer_key": "",
        "consumer_secret": "",
        "access_token": "",
        "access_token_secret": ""
    }
# Autentificamos y relizamos el proceso de log-in en Twitter
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(
        twitter_auth_keys['consumer_key'],
        twitter_auth_keys['consumer_secret']
    )
    auth.set_access_token(
        twitter_auth_keys['access_token'],
        twitter_auth_keys['access_token_secret']
    )
    api = tweepy.API(auth)


    # Realizamos un proceso de cambio de directorio de trabajo
    back = os.getcwd()
    os.chdir("pics/")

    # Definimos la variable de subida de la imagen que vamos a utilizar
    media = api.media_upload(var)

    # Definimos cual es el texto que va a utilzar el tweet como status
    tweet = var

    # Posteamos el tweet con la imagen
    post_result = api.update_status(status=tweet, media_ids=[media.media_id])

    # Movemos la foto que se ha utilizado a una carpeta diferente para que no se vuelva a utilizar
    shutil.move(var, "used/")

    # Vuelta al directorio padre
    os.chdir(back)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Fijate que valor devuelve `os.getcwd`. Es desde ahi que se hace el cambio de directorio.

Comment: `os.getcwd` devuelve el directorio en el que está alojado el script de Python, pero está así aposta porque tengo las fotos en un subdirectorio, hago que cambie, coja las fotos, las mueva cuando las usa y vuelva a su posición original, pero no sé por qué me da ese error, porque cuando lo ejecuto manualmente, ese error no existe, no hay error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que estas corriendo el mismo scripts en dos directorios distintos.

Cuando `cron` ejecuta, hace un `cd` implicito al directorio home del usuario asignado. Si estás ejecutando como *root*, el directorio será `/root`. Si estás como tu propio usuario, *victor*, tu directorio será `/home/victor`. Y claro, el subdirectorio "pics/" no está en ninguno de los dos.

La solución es hacer un cd al directorio apropiado al partir. Esto lo puedes hacer con un cambio de directorio en el mismo crontab:

```
# m h dom mon dow user  command
*  *    * * *   victor  cd /home/victor/PycharmProjects/PybotProject && /usr/bin/python3 /home/victor/PycharmProjects/PybotProject/Post.py
```

También podrías modificar el programa para que reciba el directorio como argumento opcional. Si no pones nada, opera con el directorio actual.